# How do I store an Object in an array, rather than a reference to the Object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, while-loop

I have a loop where I am storing an object that has been updated into the next place in an array. PHP is storing a reference to the object, and not storing the object in the array. So, at the end of my loop, my array contains many references to the most recent version of the object all containing the same information. How do I store an instance of the object in each iteration of the loop?

```
while( $Row = $Query->fetch_object() ) {
  $Company->id = $Row->id;
  $Company->json = json_decode($Row->json);
  $companies[] = $Company;
}
```

Comment: try to use a array_push and after loop return it?

Comment: `Clone` works. Why is this? I can't believe I've never encountered this problem before. When I just store $Row straight out of the database to an array, it doesn't store a reference to $Row, it stores the object. WTF?

Comment: What is the exact *problem* you're referring to? PHP works like this for years, and there are many articles about this behaviour and why it's there.  Had it work the way you thought it does, we'd be having a huge lack of memory at our hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new object in each iteration by either:

1. Instantiating a new object `$newObj = new CompanyClass();` or
2. Cloning the old object `$newObj = clone $Company;`

Keep in mind though that PHP performs a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.

```
while( $Row = $Query->fetch_object() ) {
  $newCompany = clone $Company; //or new CompanyClass();
  $newCompany->id = $Row->id;
  $newCompany->json = json_decode($Row->json);
  $companies[] = $newCompany;
}
```

Comment: hmm ... I think I understand. So PHP recognizes my `$Company` object as the same everywhere, unless I instantiate a new copy of it, at which point, PHP knows it's a different object even thought the variable name is the same? This is a confusing behavior and I can't believe I've never encountered it in this fashion before.

Comment: It's not a weird behavior, it's pretty common among OOP languages. In PHP, Objects are passed as references while primitives are passed as value.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks.